# Angular - Browser não atualiza após alterações no código

Tags: angular

Estou usando Angular (versão 4) e minhas alterações no código não fazem com que seja feito um build automático da aplicação.

O padrão é fazer as alterações no código e já dar o build automático, conforme get started do próprio Angular.

Esse é meu app.module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AdminLayoutComponent,
    AuthLayoutComponent,
    BreadcrumbsComponent,
    TitleComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    SharedModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes),
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    ScrollModule,
    NgDatepickerModule
  ],
  exports: [ScrollModule],
  providers: [
    UserService, {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: TokenInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    UnitService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Eu estou rodando com a aplicação com ng serve através de um terminal linux. Já testei direto no Visual Studio Code, porém sem sucesso também.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse problema pode ser permissão de pasta, tenta executar como root, pois o ng serve já é por padrão com hot reload.
Também pode ser versão do navegador usando.
Atualiza versão do nodejs que também pode corrigir.

Comment: Fabio, era problema de permissão mesmo. Rodei com root e deu boa.

Obrigado!